# JList not updating on separate pane (Swing, Java)

Tags: java, swing, jlist

On my first tab called Password Vault I have a JList with a list of "websites" that store a password. On the second tab I have an add "password" function. When I add the password the JList gets updated on the pane only. When I switch back to the other tab "password vault" it has not been updated. When I relaunch the program it has been updated. I use a field so it's not an issue of local variables.

```
public final class PasswordManagerView1 extends JFrame
    implements PasswordManagerView, ListSelectionListener {
/**
 * JList.
 */
private JList<String> list;

/**
 * JButtons.
 */
private JButton enter, unlock, reset, buttonAddEnter;

/**
 * Controller.
 */
private PasswordManagerController controller;

/**
 * Dimensions.
 */
private Dimension maxSize;

/**
 * JTabbedPanes.
 */
private JTabbedPane tabbedPane;

/**
 * JTextField.
 */
private JTextField passwordDisplay, textField;

/**
 * PasswordField.
 */
private JPasswordField passwordField, resetField, passwordFieldadd;

/**
 * Useful Constants.
 */
private static final int MAX_SIZE_HORI = 800, MAX_SIZE_VERTI = 400,
        EMPTY_BORDER_SIZE = 5;

/**
 * Constructor.
 */
public PasswordManagerView1() {
    super("Password Manager");
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    //Initial JPanel creation
    tabbedPane.setBorder(
            new EmptyBorder(PasswordManagerView1.EMPTY_BORDER_SIZE,
                    PasswordManagerView1.EMPTY_BORDER_SIZE,
                    PasswordManagerView1.EMPTY_BORDER_SIZE,
                    PasswordManagerView1.EMPTY_BORDER_SIZE));
    this.maxSize = new Dimension(PasswordManagerView1.MAX_SIZE_HORI,
            PasswordManagerView1.MAX_SIZE_VERTI);
    tabbedPane.setPreferredSize(this.maxSize);
    this.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane);

    //Initial JTabbedPane creation

    //Tab creation
    JComponent panel1 = this.makePasswordVault();
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("lock-icon.png");
    tabbedPane.addTab("Password Vault", icon, panel1,
            "View the passwords in the vault");
    JComponent panel3 = this.makeAddPanel("Add Password");
    tabbedPane.addTab("Add Password", icon, panel3,
            "Add passwords to the vault");
    //JComponent panel2 = this.makeAddPanel("ALSO ADDS");
    //tabbedPane.addTab("Delete Password", icon, panel2,
    //        "Deletes a password from the vault");

    JComponent panel4 = this.makeInfoPanel();
    tabbedPane.addTab("Info", icon, panel4,
            "View settings and program info");
    //Pack up
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.pack();
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public JComponent makeAddPanel(String text) {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(null);
    //Creation of string array of with stores
    String[] listContentC = this.getStore();

    this.list = new JList<>(listContentC);
    this.list.setBounds(0, 0, 233, 360);
    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(this.list);
    pane.setBounds(0, 0, 233, 360);
    panel.add(pane);
    JLabel labelAdd = new JLabel("Add Password");
    labelAdd.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    labelAdd.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 24));
    labelAdd.setBounds(427, 38, 163, 31);
    panel.add(labelAdd);

    this.passwordFieldadd = new JPasswordField();
    this.passwordFieldadd.setBounds(536, 100, 116, 22);
    panel.add(this.passwordFieldadd);

    this.textField = new JTextField();
    this.textField.setBounds(375, 100, 116, 22);
    panel.add(this.textField);

    JLabel lblWebsite = new JLabel("Website");
    lblWebsite.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lblWebsite.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 13));
    lblWebsite.setBounds(401, 126, 56, 16);
    panel.add(lblWebsite);

    JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Password");
    lblPassword.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lblPassword.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 13));
    lblPassword.setBounds(566, 126, 56, 16);
    panel.add(lblPassword);

    this.buttonAddEnter = new JButton("Enter");
    this.buttonAddEnter.setBounds(465, 161, 97, 25);
    panel.add(this.buttonAddEnter);
    this.buttonAddEnter.addActionListener(this);
    return panel;
}

@Override
public JComponent makeInfoPanel() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
    StringBuilder toPrint = new StringBuilder();
    SimpleReader in = new SimpleReader1L("data/Notice.txt");
    while (!in.atEOS()) {
        toPrint.append(in.nextLine() + "\n");
    }
    String toPrintString = toPrint.toString();
    JTextArea noticeText = new JTextArea(toPrintString);
    noticeText.setEditable(false);
    JScrollPane noticeTextScroll = new JScrollPane(noticeText);
    panel.add(noticeTextScroll);
    in.close();
    return panel;

}

@Override
public JComponent makePasswordVault() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(null);
    /*
     * Ask for help on this.
     *
     * I would have liked to create the listContentC by passing nothing into
     * the controller and then the controller using the model to extract the
     * data from a text file. However, my array was always initialized to
     * something null and caused a runtime error.
     *
     *
     */

    //Creation of string array of with stores
    String[] listContentC = this.getStore();

    //GUI setup of list
    this.list = new JList<>(listContentC);
    this.list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
    this.list.addListSelectionListener(this);
    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(this.list);
    pane.setBounds(0, 0, 233, 360);
    panel.add(pane);

    //The label creation (for instructions)
    JLabel labelA = new JLabel("the store and press enter!");
    labelA.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 13));
    labelA.setBounds(294, 70, 157, 31);
    panel.add(labelA);
    JLabel labelB = new JLabel("To view a password, click on");
    labelB.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 13));
    labelB.setBounds(284, 54, 163, 31);
    panel.add(labelB);

    //Enter button creation
    this.enter = new JButton("Enter");
    this.enter.setBounds(303, 128, 116, 25);
    panel.add(this.enter);
    this.enter.setEnabled(false);
    this.enter.addActionListener(this);

    //Password Display field creation
    this.passwordDisplay = new JTextField();
    this.passwordDisplay.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    this.passwordDisplay.setEditable(false);
    this.passwordDisplay
            .setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 13));
    this.passwordDisplay.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    this.passwordDisplay.setText("");
    this.passwordDisplay.setBounds(303, 247, 116, 22);
    panel.add(this.passwordDisplay);
    this.passwordDisplay.setColumns(10);

    //Password Label creation
    JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password:");
    passwordLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    passwordLabel.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 13));
    passwordLabel.setBounds(336, 218, 56, 16);
    panel.add(passwordLabel);

    //Master password notice
    JLabel mastPass = new JLabel("Enter master password to unlock vault:");
    mastPass.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 13));
    mastPass.setBounds(532, 54, 218, 31);
    panel.add(mastPass);

    //Password Field
    this.passwordField = new JPasswordField();
    this.passwordField.setBounds(532, 128, 116, 24);
    panel.add(this.passwordField);

    //Unlock button
    this.unlock = new JButton("Unlock");
    this.unlock.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 13));
    this.unlock.setBounds(660, 127, 97, 25);
    panel.add(this.unlock);
    this.unlock.addActionListener(this);

    //New setup label
    JLabel labelC = new JLabel("Reset/Set up new master pass:");
    labelC.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    labelC.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 13));
    labelC.setBounds(532, 217, 218, 16);
    panel.add(labelC);

    //New setup label
    JLabel defaultLabel = new JLabel("Default Password = \"password\"");
    defaultLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    defaultLabel.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 13));
    defaultLabel.setBounds(560, 77, 171, 16);
    panel.add(defaultLabel);

    this.resetField = new JPasswordField();
    this.resetField.setBounds(532, 246, 116, 24);
    panel.add(this.resetField);

    this.reset = new JButton("Update");
    this.reset.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 13));
    this.reset.setBounds(660, 245, 97, 25);
    this.reset.setEnabled(false);
    panel.add(this.reset);
    this.reset.addActionListener(this);
    return panel;
}

@Override
public String[] getStore() {

    int storeCount = 0;
    SimpleReader in = new SimpleReader1L("data/store.txt");
    while (!in.atEOS()) {
        storeCount++;
        in.nextLine();
    }
    in.close();
    String[] listContentC = new String[storeCount];
    SimpleReader in2 = new SimpleReader1L("data/store.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < storeCount; i++) {
        listContentC[i] = in2.nextLine();
    }
    in2.close();
    return listContentC;
}

@Override
public void registerObserver(PasswordManagerController controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
}

@Override
public void updateEnterButtonVaultTab(boolean result) {
    this.enter.setEnabled(result);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    //Wait cursor
    this.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));

    //What button was pressed
    Object source = event.getSource();
    if (source == this.enter) {
        int index = this.list.getSelectedIndex();
        System.out.println(index);
        if (this.list.getSelectedIndex() != -1) {
            this.controller.processEnterEvent(this.list.getSelectedValue());
        }
    } else if (source == this.unlock) {
        this.controller
                .processUnlockEvent(this.passwordField.getPassword());
    } else if (source == this.reset) {
        this.controller.processResetEvent(this.resetField.getPassword());
    } else if (source == this.buttonAddEnter) {
        this.controller.processAddEvent(this.textField.getText(),
                this.passwordFieldadd.getPassword());
        //needs done in model
        this.updateListModel();
    }
    this.setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
}

@Override
public void updateListModel() {
    //MOVE TO THE MODEL
    String[] temp = this.getStore();
    DefaultListModel<String> temp2 = new DefaultListModel<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
        temp2.addElement(temp[i]);
    }
    this.list.setModel(temp2);
}

@Override
public JTabbedPane getTabbedPane() {
    return this.tabbedPane;
}

@Override
public void setTabbedPane(JTabbedPane tabbedPane) {
    this.tabbedPane = tabbedPane;
}

@Override
public void updatePasswordField() {
    this.passwordField.setText("");
}

@Override
public void updateResetPasswordDisplay() {
    this.resetField.setText("");
}

@Override
public void displayWrongPass() {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Wrong password entered!");

}

@Override
public void displayUpdatedPass() {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Master password updated!");
}

@Override
public void updateResetButton(boolean result) {
    this.reset.setEnabled(result);
}

@Override
public void updatePasswordDisplay(char[] password) {
    StringBuilder passwordCreation = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < password.length; i++) {
        passwordCreation.append(password[i]);
    }
    this.passwordDisplay.setText(passwordCreation.toString());

}

@Override
public JComponent makeTextPanel(String text) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent arg0) {

}

}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). I.E. an MCVE/SSCCE should include the imports needed to compile it, a `main(String[])` method to run it, and cut out any code not explicitly needed in order to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I second @AndrewThompson's suggestion. I don't see an obvious cause for the error above, and it may be how you're making connections, perhaps creating more than one PasswordManagerView instance -- hard to say. To avoid having us guess, create your [mcve] or [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: A side issue is your use of null layouts. While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, to display multiple JLists, all displaying the same content, then all should share the same model. If you do this, then changes made to one JList will be reflected in all the others, since the changes are not actually made to the JList per se (which only displays the model's content) but rather to the shared model. To understand this, you will want to read up on the MVC or Model-View-Controller design pattern, since Swing components use a *variant* of this.

For example, please see the code below where I created 3 JPanels, each with its own JList, but have them all share the same `DefaultListModel<String>`. Note that I have all 3 JPanels extend from a parent class that actually holds the JList and accepts the model in its constructor. Then if I add list items in one JPanel or remove them in another, they all display in all the lists of the 3 JPanels. Also check out how I minimized the code to be close to the smallest needed to compile, run, and show the problem or solution, a [minimal code example program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or MCVE:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class PanelsWithSharedList extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 400;
    private static final int PREF_H = 250;
    private JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    private DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();

    public PanelsWithSharedList() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            listModel.addElement("List element " + (i + 1));
        }

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(tabbedPane);
        tabbedPane.add("Panel 1", new ListShowingPanel1(listModel));
        tabbedPane.add("Panel 2", new ListShowingPanel2(listModel));
        tabbedPane.add("Panel 3", new ListShowingPanel3(listModel));
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        Dimension superSz = super.getPreferredSize();
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return superSz;
        }
        int prefW = Math.max(superSz.width, PREF_W);
        int prefH = Math.max(superSz.height, PREF_H);
        return new Dimension(prefW, prefH);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        PanelsWithSharedList mainPanel = new PanelsWithSharedList();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Panels With Shared List");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
abstract class AbstractListShowingPanel extends JPanel {
    private JList<String> list;

    public AbstractListShowingPanel(DefaultListModel<String> listModel) {
        list = new JList<>(listModel);
        list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    }

    public JList<String> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public DefaultListModel<String> getModel() {
        return (DefaultListModel<String>) list.getModel();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class ListShowingPanel1 extends AbstractListShowingPanel {
    private JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);

    public ListShowingPanel1(DefaultListModel<String> listModel) {
        super(listModel);
        add(new JScrollPane(getList()));
        add(new JLabel("Text to add:"));

        Action action = new AddTextAction();
        textField.setAction(action);
        add(textField);
        add(new JButton(action));

    }

    private class AddTextAction extends AbstractAction {
        public AddTextAction() {
            super("Add Text");
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_A);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            getModel().addElement(textField.getText());
            textField.selectAll();
        }
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class ListShowingPanel2 extends AbstractListShowingPanel {
    public ListShowingPanel2(DefaultListModel<String> listModel) {
        super(listModel);
        add(new JScrollPane(getList()));
        add(new JButton(new DeleteItemAction()));
    }

    private class DeleteItemAction extends AbstractAction {
        public DeleteItemAction() {
            super("Delete Selected Item");
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_D);
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JList<String> list = getList();
            String selection = list.getSelectedValue();
            if (selection != null) {
                getModel().removeElement(selection);
            }
        }
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class ListShowingPanel3 extends AbstractListShowingPanel {
    public ListShowingPanel3(DefaultListModel<String> listModel) {
        super(listModel);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JScrollPane(getList()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your constructor calls makePasswordPanel() which has this line:

```
   this.list = new JList<>(listContentC);
```

The constructor then calls makeAddPanel() which has this line:

```
   this.list = new JList<>(listContentC);
```

So now you have thrown away the handle to the first list and replaced it with a reference to the new list. Then in your updateListModel, you change the model for this.list (which is the makeAddPanel list). There is no way to also update the model for the password panel, since you have discarded the reference to that panel.

Comment: Good eyes, well spotted

Comment: Thanks, now my thought for fixing this would be to create a field called list that is initialized globally. However, when I do that only the most recent addition of that pane is actually added to the GUI. Anything before that doesn't even have a JList. I confirmed this by switching around which panes are created first. It's always the last pane to request the JList that gets to actually keep the JList. Any pane before that just doesn't have one.

Comment: @frillybob: yes create multiple JList, but ony create one model that they all share. Again, in the future you should work to simplify your posted code so that your questions are easier to answer. Please please read the links that we've given to you in comments to the main question so that your future questions aren't so hard to answer.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I will do that in the future. How can I actually add the same list (which is inside of a scroll frame) to multiple panels. I just create the one JList and JScrollPane and declare them in a field. Then I instantiate them globally. But when I add them only the latest addition shows up in the pane.

Comment: *"I will do that in the future. How can I actually.."* I'll field that one .. in the future.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I think you knew what I meant. In future new posts I'll post with the proper guidelines. However, this time I feel like I'm just missing something simple that could potentially be answered by someone that has already taken a look at the code. Thank you guys for the help.

Comment: *"I think you knew what I meant."* If you couldn't be bothered editing your current question to include an MCVE/SSCCE, why should we bother to try to help you further? You've already seen the answers (now two of them) that seem to have failed to solve the problem. The ball is in your court.

Comment: @frillybob: I told you how -- you don't. You add separate JLists as you're doing, but all these JLists **share the same model**. Swing components follow a variant of the MVC design pattern, and if the components share a model, they will show the same data.

Answer (score 0):

Just from an academic point of view, I would suggest that this kind of relationship between graphic elements and subjacent data models should be implemented as an Observer pattern (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).  The way you have shown us you are doing it, may soon become confusing and hard to maintain when you start having 5 or 6 GUI elements all reacting to changes in the same shared data structure.

Comment: I  called repaint() in the code but didn't know where to put it. I then moved it to the panel creation as per your suggestion but it didn't do anything. I also tried updating the list model after pressing the "unlock" button  by adding a method call to updateListModel() in the unlock event, and to my surprise that actually didn't update the list as I thought it would

Comment: Yes, repaint is a bad answer, please delete that section of the answer. This is never needed when updating a component via its default model since it's already called by the default model.